# Ghostscript Can not find Ghostscript library (libgs)

Tags: python, ghostscript

I'm on a macbookpro 10.6.8 and I get this error message when trying to use ghostscript:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arnoutaertgeerts/Documents/Eclips/SlideTalk 2.0/slidetalk.py", line 13, in <module>
    import ghostscript
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ghostscript-0.4.1-py2.7.egg/ghostscript/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import _gsprint as gs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ghostscript-0.4.1-py2.7.egg/ghostscript/_gsprint.py", line 290, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('Can not find Ghostscript library (libgs)')
RuntimeError: Can not find Ghostscript library (libgs)
```

Installed the package with:

```
pip install ghostscript
```

Answer (score 1):

For newer user who are using M1 mac, ghostscript might show a missing libgs file error and the file would be unavailable at `usr/local/lib`

The issue can be resolved by following these steps, in the same order:

- `brew install ghostscript`
- `conda install ghostscript`, which installs the arm_64 based library from conda-forge
- If conda throws a channel error try using `conda install -c conda-forge ghostscript`
- `pip install ghostscript`

Note:

1. The libgs.dylib file can be found in the home brew installation of ghostscript
2. Changing the address in `_gsprint.py` will throw an error as the brew installed version will be arm_64 based and the pip installed version will be OS_X86 based
3. Python doesn't recognise ghostscript module from conda install unless pip install is run, so that is an essential step

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to 'use' Ghostscript ? This seems to be an error from Python which can't find libgs (I do not speak Python I'm afraid)

I'm not certain that libgs is is included in the Mac installation but if it is, then libgs should be in the Ghostscript folder. Have you checked to see if it is present ?

If it is, then the most likely problem is that its not in the search path, I have no idea how searches are resolved on a Mac though.

Comment: Yes I found it here: /opt/local/lib/libgs.dylib

Comment: and is that in the Mac search path ? I would suspect not, maybe try putting in /usr/local/bin (again I know nothing much about MacOS, so this may be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

The ctypes.find_library searches in /urs/local/lib.

I added this path to my ghostscript module:

```
/opt/local/lib/libgs
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the path for libgs in the file "_gsprint.py" and it works~

Instead of libgs.so (libgs = cdll.LoadLibrary("libgs.so"), I used
libgs = cdll.LoadLibrary("Corresponding_Path_in_my_laptop/libgs.dylib").

Ps: There's no libgs.so on my Mac, only one libgs.dylib file.

Thanks @KenS and @arnoutaertgeerts!